# Как вывести все id таблицы spring jpa,boot

Tags: java, jpa

Есть класс таблицы

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "category")
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class Category {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
}
```

не знаю как вывести все id, заранее спасибо.

Comment: а можно спросить зачем нужен список всех id? чем не устраивает метод репозитория findAll() ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создайте в репозитории метод

```
@Query( "SELECT c.id FROM Сategory c" )
public List<Long> findAllId();
```

Comment: а зачем нужно c?

Comment: вы задаете алиас , потом через него считываете поле id. Это JPA запрос построенный на сущноси и полях

Comment: @Query("SELECT c.id FROM category c")
    public List<Long> findAllId(); пишет не может определить символ категория

Comment: Category с большой буквы - это класс

Comment: заработало!!! большое спасибо